# R: sequence of days between dates

Tags: r, date, seq

I have the following dataframes:

```
AllDays  
2012-01-01  
2012-01-02  
2012-01-03  
...  
2015-08-18  

Leases 
StartDate  EndDate
2012-01-01 2013-01-01  
2012-05-07 2013-05-06  
2013-09-05 2013-12-01
```

What I want to do is, for each date in the allDays dataframe, calculate the number of leases that are in effect. e.g. if there are 4 leases with start date <= 2015-01-01 and end date >= 2015-01-01, then I would like to place a 4 in that dataframe.

I have the following code

```
  for (i in 1:nrow(leases))
  {
    occupied = seq(leases$StartDate[i],leases$EndDate[i],by="days")
    occupied = occupied[occupied < dateOfInt]
    matching = match(occupied,allDays$Date)
    allDays$Occupancy[matching] = allDays$Occupancy[matching] + 1
  }
```

which works, but as I have about 5000 leases, it takes about 1.1 seconds. Does anyone have a more efficient method that would require less computation time?
Date of interest is just the current date and is used simply to ensure that it doesn't count lease dates in the future.

Comment: are all of the dates stored as `Date` variables? seems like something for `foverlaps`, but i still don't know how to use that function :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `seq` is almost surely inefficient--imagine you had a lease in your data that's 10000 years long. `seq` will take forever and return 10000*365-1 days that don't matter to us. We then have to use `%in%` which also makes the same number of unnecessary comparisons.

I'm not sure the following is the best approach (I'm convinced there's a fully vectorized solution) but it gets closer to the heart of the problem.

## Data

```
set.seed(102349)
days<-data.frame(AllDays=seq(as.Date("2012-01-01"),
                             as.Date("2015-08-18"),"day"))

leases<-data.frame(StartDate=sample(days$AllDays,5000L,T))
leases$EndDate<-leases$StartDate+round(rnorm(5000,mean=365,sd=100))
```

## Approach

Use `data.table` and `sapply`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(leases); setDT(days)

days[,lease_count:=
       sapply(AllDays,function(x)
         leases[StartDate<=x&EndDate>=x,.N])][]
         AllDays lease_count
   1: 2012-01-01           5
   2: 2012-01-02           8
   3: 2012-01-03          11
   4: 2012-01-04          16
   5: 2012-01-05          18
  ---                       
1322: 2015-08-14        1358
1323: 2015-08-15        1358
1324: 2015-08-16        1360
1325: 2015-08-17        1363
1326: 2015-08-18        1359
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I keep getting an error saying that `the longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: sorry, my mistake! It works! Takes just over 0.5 seconds, much better! Thanks so much!

Comment: This is exactly the problem where `foverlaps` shines: `setkey(days[, AllDays1:=AllDays,], AllDays, AllDays1);setkey(leases, StartDate, EndDate);foverlaps(leases, days)[, .(lease_count=.N), AllDays]`

Comment: @khashaa yes! please post with benchmarks to demonstrate just how dominant it is, I believe that's the better answer.

Comment: @MichaelChirico Since it is based off of your example, why don't you add it to your answer.

Comment: @khashaa I hate to steal your thunder--I honestly don't understand how `foverlaps` works yet so I would never have used it

Comment: @MichaelChirico, thanks again for this solution. Wanted to ask a quick question. How would I update the function if, instead of simply counting the number of occurrences, there was a third column, amount, that I wanted to sum over? Thanks again!

Comment: hey @Mike, first, I recommend using the `foverlaps` approach suggested in khashaa's answer--it's the canonical way to handle this class of problems. That said, both of our answers can be adjusted by swapping `.N` for `sum(var3)`, or any expression involving the columns of your data, really.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly the problem where foverlaps shines: subsetting a data.frame based upon another data.frame (`foverlaps` seems to be tailored for that purpose).

Based on @MichaelChirico's data.

```
setkey(days[, AllDays1:=AllDays,], AllDays, AllDays1)
setkey(leases, StartDate, EndDate)
foverlaps(leases, days)[, .(lease_count=.N), AllDays]
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.114   0.018   0.136
# @MichaelChirico's approach
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.909   0.000   0.907
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28578977/1) is a brief explanation on how it works by @Arun, which got me started with the `data.table`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.. :-(. And humbled to know that that answer got you started with dt.

Answer (score 2):

Without your data, I can't test whether or not this is faster, but it gets the job done with less code:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(AllDays)) AllDays$tally[i] = sum(AllDays$AllDays[i] >= Leases$Start.Date & AllDays$AllDays[i] <= Leases$End.Date)
```

I used the following to test it; note that the relevant columns in both data frames are formatted as dates:

```
AllDays = data.frame(AllDays = seq(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"), to=as.Date("2015-08-18"), by=1))
Leases = data.frame(Start.Date = as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2012-08-20", "2014-06-01")), End.Date = as.Date(c("2013-12-31", "2014-12-31", "2015-05-31")))
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach, but I'm not sure it's faster.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

AllDays = data.frame(dates = c("2012-02-01","2012-03-02","2012-04-03"))

Lease = data.frame(start = c("2012-01-03","2012-03-01","2012-04-02"),
                   end = c("2012-02-05","2012-04-15","2012-07-11"))

# transform to dates
AllDays$dates = ymd(AllDays$dates)
Lease$start = ymd(Lease$start)
Lease$end = ymd(Lease$end)

# create the range id
Lease$id = 1:nrow(Lease)

AllDays

#        dates
# 1 2012-02-01
# 2 2012-03-02
# 3 2012-04-03

Lease

#       start        end id
# 1 2012-01-03 2012-02-05  1
# 2 2012-03-01 2012-04-15  2
# 3 2012-04-02 2012-07-11  3


data.frame(expand.grid(AllDays$dates,Lease$id)) %>%      # create combinations of dates and ranges
  select(dates=Var1, id=Var2) %>%
  inner_join(Lease, by="id") %>%                         # join information
  rowwise %>%
  do(data.frame(dates=.$dates,
                flag = ifelse(.$dates %in% seq(.$start,.$end,by="1 day"),1,0))) %>%     # create ranges and check if the date is in there
  ungroup %>%
  group_by(dates) %>%
  summarise(N=sum(flag))

#        dates N
# 1 2012-02-01 1
# 2 2012-03-02 1
# 3 2012-04-03 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the lubridate package. Create an interval for each lease. Then count the lease intervals which each date falls in.

```
# make some data
AllDays <- data.frame("Days" = seq.Date(as.Date("2012-01-01"), as.Date("2012-02-01"), by = 1))
Leases <- data.frame("StartDate" = as.Date(c("2012-01-01", "2012-01-08")),
                 "EndDate" = as.Date(c("2012-01-10", "2012-01-21")))
library(lubridate)

x <- new_interval(Leases$StartDate, Leases$EndDate, tzone = "UTC")
AllDays$NumberInEffect <- sapply(AllDays$Days, function(a){sum(a %within% x)})
```

The Output

```
head(AllDays)
        Days NumberInEffect
1 2012-01-01              1
2 2012-01-02              1
3 2012-01-03              1
4 2012-01-04              1
5 2012-01-05              1
6 2012-01-06              1
```